# Finding element in aspx by property (not Id)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a  that would result in some uncompilable code in the designer.cs file:

```
<div id="tabs-1-2-3"></div>
```

If I add a `runat="server"` property, my designer file won't compile for obvious reasons.

Is there any way to add an extra property that wil be used internally as the id?

Comment: By "Internally" you mean in the code behind or in the client code?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have runat="server" then you can access it through the old school way.

```
<input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" />
```

then from server side use

```
Request["text1"]
```

for div:
The best way to do this would be some form of ajax, since your client side script would be able to read that contents and pass it to a server side method
Access in code behind isn't possiable without runat="server" attributes

Answer (score 0):

Use an `<asp:Panel />` which will turn into a `<div>` in the HTML page.

Comment: and hows that answer the Q ? –

Comment: @RoyiNamir an `<asp:Panel>` can have `runat=server` and a server `ID`